# I can spin up a react server and rails server on Mac but local host doesn’t Work on browser

Tags: reactjs, macos, localhost, webserver

I am not sure what to do. It just spins for a while and then says page isn’t responding in chrome.

I’m running on the latest macOS, any help on how to start troubleshooting this would be appreciated.

I was working in the app on local host previously and then it just stopped working.

This was resolved. I deleted my package.json file and reinstalled with npm. Apparently one of the node modules had updated and changed the configuration for my webpack server. Still looking into how this happened.

Comment: After starting the server, is there any output suggesting that the server encountered an error?

Comment: No not in the terminal everything is normal and npm says compiled successfully and it says I can view in browser on local host. Same for rails, it says listening on port 3000